# Input values through a user-defined function in a column of a pandas dataframe when a certain condition is given

Tags: python, pandas, function, input

I have a pandas DataFrame with a column "A" representing a categorical variable that may have unknown values, marked as "-1". I would like to replace the unknown values by a randomly generated sample of the variable, taking into account their frequencies.

Example:

```py
    'A' 
0   cat
1   dog
2   -1
3   dog
4   dog
```

Input the "-1" value to a random sample of (cat, dog) with probability of choice their counts, i.e., (1,3)

I can easily obtain the possible values and counters through

```py
vals, counts = np.unique(df['A'], return_counts=True),
```

and then with

```py
random.choices(vals, counts)
```

I can take samples of them, so the function is built.

How can I replace the entries "-1" of the column by the output value of applying the function?

Comment: It would help understand your question if we had sample input and output, but possibly something like `df['A']=np.where(df['A'] == -1,func(),df['A']`?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Comment: Since it solved your issue I've moved my comment to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help understand your question if we had sample input and output, but you should be able to use `np.where` on the series
Something like

```
df['A']=np.where(df['A'] == -1,func(),df['A']
```